# How to scale a binary mask pattern

Tags: python, matrix, scaling, binary-data

**DISCLAIMER**:

I am doing this for an art project that combines history with mathematics.

**QUESTION:**

Let's say I have a binary mask pattern like

`mask = [1,0,1,1,1],[1,0,1,0,0],[1,1,1,1,1],[0,0,1,0,1],[1,1,1,0,1]`

it is a 5 rows 5 columns matrix that represents a swastika pattern

[image]

**I am wondering** if there are any quick ways of obtaining an "enlarged-scaled" version of the pattern

`enlarged_mask = [1,0,0,1,1,1,1], [1,0,0,1,0,0,0], [1,0,0,1,0,0,0], [1,1,1,1,1,1,1], [0,0,0,1,0,0,1], [0,0,0,1,0,0,1], [1,1,1,1,0,0,1]`

that in this case has now 7 rows and 7 columns and *preserves the overall logic of the original pattern*.

[image]

What could be a possible handy method for the case?

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: This question is unclear, because "the overall logic of the original pattern" is not clear. There are infinitely many logics that apply to the original pattern, and it is not at all obvious which one should be used in enlarging the pattern. Could you be more specific?

Comment: Is using a image processing module an option? If it is, you could do this by converting the binary data into a bitmapped image file, scale it, and then converting the result back into zeros and ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> preserves the overall logic of the original pattern.

This is the hard bit, assuming you want an *arbitrary* pattern. You're basically after an AI capable of *discerning* this pattern, a very much non-trivial task. For example, consider the 3x3 pattern (zeros are rendered blank for readabilty):

```
111
1 1
111
```

Is this pattern "outer units set" or is it "inner unit clear"? The difference between those two is vast as the former is what you want but the latter will end up with a much thicker border line. In other words, it will be one of:

```
Outer-set       Inner-clear
=========       ===========
  11111            11111
  1   1            11111
  1   1            11 11
  1   1            11111
  11111            11111
```

That's even before you examine *other* possibilities such as simply scaling the image itself, so that you work on sub-unit resolution.

---

However, since it appears you're after a *specific* pattern (known in advance), you can generate a single-pixel width swastika with the following code:

```
def swastika(n):
    # Ignore requests for malformed images.

    if n < 1 or n % 2 == 0: return []
    matrix = [[0 for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]

    # Do the cross bit.

    for i in range(n):
        matrix[n//2][i] = 1
        matrix[i][n//2] = 1

    # Do the outer arms.

    for i in range(n//2,n):
        matrix[0][i] = 1
        matrix[i][n-1] = 1
        matrix[n-1][n-i-1] = 1
        matrix[n-i-1][0] = 1

    return matrix

# Test harness for various sizes.

for i in range(5, 10, 2):
    s = swastika(i)
    for j in range(i):
        print(s[j])
    print()
```

The output of that is (modified for readability, yet again):

```
                     1   11111
         1  1111     1   1
1 111    1  1        1   1
1 1      1  1        1   1
11111    1111111     111111111
  1 1       1  1         1   1
111 1       1  1         1   1
         1111  1         1   1
                     11111   1
```

Comment: @Loss: sure, if the *rule* is known in advance rather than trying to discern the rule from a bitmap. Otherwise, see my paragraph re "Anything other than a fixed pattern will, as mentioned, require a fair bit of AI." :-)

Comment: I'm trying to scale a swastika-pattern for an art project. I could edit my question with the `matrix = [1,0,1,1,1],[1,0,1,0,0],[1,1,1,1,1],[0,0,1,0,1],[1,1,1,0,1]`I sent you. Could be possible for you to elaborate your answer in order to do so?

Comment: @Loss, see the update. I've added a section for the specific requirement.

Comment: Thank you a lot, it did the job perfectly. Do you think the overall thickness of the lines could also be preserved in the function implementation? Namely, not having the pattern get skinnier and skinnier at the increase of n but preserve a overall acceptable thickness.

Comment: @Loss, it could be, yes. However, I'd suggest asking that as *another* question, linking back to this if needed. I've already had to make massive changes to the answer based on your question edits so I'd prefer not to have to do that again. Preserving the thickness will basically mean figuring out the ration of line width to image size (ratio of 1:6) but ensuring that width is always the closest integer. That's best done as a separate issue, I think.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your great expertise and kindness

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just want a 2D matrix with the very outer edges set. In numpy:

```
import numpy as np

n = 5 # or 3 or whatever
mask = np.ones((n, n), dtype=int)
mask[1:-1,1:-1] = 0
print(mask)
```

Result:

```
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Comment: "It looks like you just want a 2D matrix with the very outer edges set", no. The pattern specified in the question is just an example case.I am interested in algorithms able to solve the generic scenario

Comment: In that case, the question is far too broad to be answered. There is no simple algorithm to discern a pattern, especially from a measly 3x3 array.